# Do the Chain Rule

Tags: code-golf, math, calculus

We've had a lot of challenges on differentiation and integration, but none on just solving related rates problems. So in this challenge, you will get a bunch of derivatives (They will be numeric, not in terms of any variables) and have to find another derivative.

The input will come in a newline separated list of equations, in the form `dx/dt = 4`. There can be decimals and negatives.

The input will end with one differential, the one you will have to find. You can assume there will always be enough information to find it, butt there may also be excess information.

You may also have to consider the derivative of the inverse function, e.g. if you have `dy/dx = 3`, you also know that `dx/dy = 1/3`.

Your output will be in the form `dy/dt = 6`. All the whitespace, etc. has to be the same. Assume all variables are always one letter (They can be uppercase, and they can be `d`).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

### Test Cases

```
dy/dx = 4
dx/dt = 5
dy/dt

answer: dy/dt = 20

dy/dx = -3
dt/dx = 3
dy/dt

answer: dy/dt = -1

dA/dt = 4
dA/dC = 2
dC/dr = 6.28
dr/dt

answer: dr/dt = 0.3184713375796178

dx/dy = 7
dx/dt = 0
dy/dt

answer: dy/dt = 0
```

Comment: Is the output "answer: dx/dt = .318" or just "dx/dt = .318"?

Comment: @GamrCorps the latter.

Comment: Can we use built-in equation solvers?

Comment: I have a feeling answers will treat `d_/d_` as a ratio and that makes me sad

Comment: @MartinBüttner yes, but not builtin differential equation solvers.

Comment: Will there ever be any zero derivatives?

Comment: @MartinBüttner yes.

Comment: @Maltysen that should be a test case then ;)

Comment: @Mar true, adding.

Comment: Can there be **cycles** ? if so, then [in this example](http://i.imgur.com/3WereFM.png) where ratios are represented by edges, is it valid? or `dx/dz` must be equal to `dx/dy` × `dy/dz` (thus, in any other example, any chain from `dx` to `dz` shall always give the same result)?

Comment: @Ampora why so sad? The difference quotient *is* a ratio, and so are rates in general. There are very few situations where you *wouldn't* want to treat that as a ratio.

Comment: Is it okay to take the input surrounded with quotes (for Python 2)?

Comment: I thought I understood the chain rule, but I don't understand the last test case. Can you explain how you get that answer?

Comment: @KSFT `dx/dy = 7`, so `dy/dx = 1/7`, and therefore `dy/dt = (dy/dx)(dx/dt) = (1/7)(0) = 0`.

Comment: How much precision is required? For example, is it acceptable for the second test case, if we print -0.999999999999999?

Answer (score 3):

### Python - <s>278</s> 275

No one else has done this yet, so I thought I'd submit this, even though it isn't golfed very well yet.

```py
a={}
e={}
k=input
i=k()
while"="in i:
 b,d=i.split(" =");b,c=b.split("/");d=float(d)
 if d:a[b]=a.get(b,[])+[[c,1/d]]
 a[c]=a.get(c,[])+[[b,d]];i=k()
i=i.split("/")
def f(x):
 for j in a.get(x,[]):
  if j[0] not in e:e[j[0]]=e[x]*j[1];f(j[0])
e[i[1]]=1
f(i[1])
print(e[i[0]])
```

Here it is partially ungolfed:

```py
a={}
e={}
i=input()
while "=" in i:
 b,d=i.split(" =")
 b,c=b.split("/")
 d=float(d)
 if d:a[b]=a.get(b,[])+[[c,1/d]]
 a[c]=a.get(c,[])+[[b,d]]
 i=input()
i=i.split("/")
def f(x):
 for j in a.get(x,[]):
  if j[0] not in e:e[j[0]]=e[x]*j[1];f(j[0])
e[i[1]]=1
f(i[1])
print(e[i[0]])
```

Three bytes were saved by Thomas Kwa.